# How to check if a file exists in C tiny c compiler

Tags: c

Im using tiny c compiler and i have a problem when i try to run my program i get the message "include file 'unistd.h' not found"

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char openfile[100];
    char entercommand[100];

    scanf("%s",entercommand);
    if(entercommand == "cat.exe")
    {
        printf("please enter the name of the file : \n");
    }

    scanf("%s",openfile);
    if(access(openfile,F_OK) != -1)
    {
        printf("the file exists \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the file does not exist \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to take some time to read through your text-books and refresh some of the basics of C.

Comment: Note that in C you can't compare a string with `entercommand == "cat.exe"` but must use `strcmp(entercommand, "cat.exe")` and `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: You cannot compare strings with `entercommand == "cat.exe"`. Use `strcmp`. And before that, read the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: As for the error, `<unistd.h>` is a POSIX-specific header file, which is standard on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS. If you're on a Linux or macOS system and get this error, you haven't installed the needed development packages. Otherwise if you're on WIndows you need to use other header files and possibly other functions as well.

Comment: Using Windows? (Also you don't use `==` to compare strings)

Comment: im on windows and im using tcc(tiny c compiler)

Comment: And some nitpicking on terminology: You get the error when you *build* your program. Programming in C is a tree-step process: 1) Edit code; 2) Build code to generate an executable program; 3) Run the executable program.